# How can NN be thought of as p(x|z) in the decoder part of VAEs?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

So, you can feed random input (z) to a NN and make the output random, but that will be just f(p(z)), where f(.) is the deterministic NN, so that will act as a transformation to a more complex distribution.

The other way to introduce stochasticty is to think of the NN output as parameters of a certain distribution and as such, the NN is P(x|z). BUT, that's not happening, the decoder of a VAE is producing an image (x), and it is not random! so, for a given z, it will produce the same x, all the time.

**Why do they think of it as P(x|z) in the derivations of VAEs??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, even though the decoder part of the VAE is not stochastic, it still induces a distribution (though a degenerate one).

You feed in z (specific code) and you get x (specific image). Then it holds that- 
p(x|z) = 1 and, p(x|z') = 0 for every z' different than z.

This is still a legit distribution. And part of what we're doing in VAE is trying to learn the correct parameters of this distribution.

Comment: Correct. That's what I found later. I read that the output image can be thought of as mean of multivariate Gaussian, and the variance is so small that it only allows that output. Degenerate is good term for that distribution. Thanks.
Very few people understand VAEs, btw.